# c++: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

At first I am trying to use glad.h in my project. *Xcode 7.2.1*. gives me the `error` :

```
glad.h:26:2: OpenGL header already included, remove this include, glad already provides it.
```

These are the headers in my `main.cpp` :

```
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
```

I add `GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` to packaging - preprocessor definitions and LLVM - preprocessor macros(similar to preprocessor definitions in Visual Studio I guess?). Then the errors turn to:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glfwGetPrimaryMonitor", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove the code `#include "glad/glad.h”`, the errors remain the same. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually add `GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` to Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions, and not only in `main.cpp`?

Comment: Thank you a lot wdc. The original error has gone. || Another 3 errors come up... It would be greatly helpful if anyone know something about it.

Comment: This looks like a linker problem. Compiler can't find definitions for `_glfwCreateWindow` and `_glfwGetPrimaryMonitor`. I am not familiar with xcode, but search for a linker, and provide it with the right libraries for glfw or glad(dll,lib)

Comment: You are right wdc. It's indeed a linker problem. I forgot to add OpenGl/GL frameworks to my projects.><